# Python HTML containing special characters to PDF

Tags: html, python-3.x, pdf, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I have been using wkhtmltopdf library along with pdfkit on my windows machine to convert a bunch of html documents into pdf. The html has special characters like this " ☒ " in the text, which is getting converted to garbled characters on the pdf:

**HTML code:**

```
<p class=MsoListParagraphCxSpFirst><span style=font-family:&quot;Verdana Pro Cond&quot;,sans-serif><w:sdt checkbox=t checkboxischecked=t checkboxvaluechecked=☒ checkboxvalueunchecked=☐ checkboxfontchecked=MS Gothic checkboxfontunchecked=MS Gothic id=1216464249><span style=font-family:
 &quot;MS Gothic&quot;>☒</span></w:sdt> Name &amp; role<o:p></o:p></span></p>
```

**Actual html looks like:**

```
☒ Name & role
```

**PDF doc looks like post conversion:**

```
â˜’ Name &role
```

I tried passing the following encoding options(UTF-16, UTF-8) in the Python3 code, it isn't working:

```
options = {
    'encoding': "UTF-8"
}

pdfkit.from_file('data/file2.html','out2.pdf',options=options)
```

Any pointers will be helpful. Should I be using a different library?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now. Some of input files that I have had weren't properly formatted and  the `<html> <\html>` tags were missing.
After adding these to the start and end of the file, it worked.